# What is the expression for strong field Schwarzschild circular orbit perihelion precession?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, orbital-motion, geodesics

How can you calculate how large the perihelion shift should be under Schwarzschild conditions in general relativity for minimally disturbed circular orbits in the strong field limit?

I think there is a functioning expression that works well in the weak fields of our solar system.

What would the perihelion shift be for a minimally disturbed circular orbit just above the minimum stable circular orbit at $r=6GM/c^2$ and, for instance, at $r=9GM/c^2$, $r=12GM/c^2$ and $r=15GM/c^2$ ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics#Exact_solution_using_elliptic_functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The periapsis precession for a circular geodesic with radius $r$ in the Schwarzschild metric is

$$ 2
\pi \left( 
\sqrt{\frac{r}{r-6M}}-1\right)$$

The answer for a generic bound geodesic with (dimensionless) semilatus rectum $p$ and eccentricity $e$ is:

$$ 4\sqrt{\frac{p}{p-6+2e}}K\left(\sqrt{\frac{4e}{p-6+2e}}\right)-2\pi,$$
where $K$ is the [complete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind).

These formula's are, of course, assuming that the orbit is a geodesic and therefore that the orbiting body is a test particle whose own gravitational influence can be neglected.

Calculation of corrections due to the mass of the orbiting body can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.3331) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.0935).

Comment: Thank you. This is basically true for all r > 6M and not just a weak field approximation?

Comment: @Agerhell - Since a truly circular orbit doesn't have a periapsis it must be an approximation for small ellipticities. You can calculate it numerically as I did [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Newton_versus_Schwarzschild_trajectories.gif), but I think there was an analytical solution as well, if I find or remember it I'll come back at it. I think it might work if you replace r with r_max or r_min or something like that, but don't quote me on that (yet).

Comment: @Yukterez This is the exact circular orbit limit of the periapsis shift for Schwarzschild geodesics